AWS Glue Job Logging issue
I am facing issue on AWS Glue logs. I am using below code in my script to get logger and perform log, but all logs are printing on Error logs rather than output log group.
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
logger = glueContext.get_logger()
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

logger.info("Started Processing")

Any idea how to find it.
One Observation -
Print is going to output logs but want to use glue logger.

AWS Glue’s get_logger() sends logs to the stderr stream by default, which is why they appear in the Error Log Stream in CloudWatch.
If you prefer to stick with glueContext.get_logger() but ensure its logs appear in the Output Log Stream, you can redirect stderr to stdout
Add this line early in your script:
import sys
sys.stderr = sys.stdout
This ensures all logs, including those from the Glue logger, go to the Output Log Stream in CloudWatch

Thanks for your response. Tried above approach but not working .still logs are showing on error.
